# How does SMS_RECEIVED BroadcastReceiver starts after network state changes

Tags: android

Let's suppose network service is unavailable or you are in airplane mode and you receive an sms at that moment. How BroadcastReceiver gets triggered and how does it know that an sms has been received while there network was off or unavailable? is it the default mms app, or is it an internal service or something like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't, Airplane mode means radios are off and no service means no way for your phone to access its network, so no app can communicate with the outside world. If an sms is sent to you, your phone won't retrieve it. It will check however, the next time there is service.

Comment: Do I have to be aware of this, like is it possible that this service is not present on the user's phone, and so my app has to check it by itself if a message has been received?

Comment: I haven't worked SMS receivers yet, however, I don't think so as your listener should listen for `android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED` which I assume is a global broadcast done by the system.